# How to divide all bars in bar chart by specific bar value in TIBCO Spotfire?

Tags: bar-chart, spotfire

I am aiming to create a percentage growth Bar chart. The percentage is on basis of any one specific bar value.

For example, I have 5 fruits (Apple, Banana, Cherry, Dates, Mango) and their repective sales. The user selects a primary fruit (E.g Apple) and than selects a secondary fruit (E.g Mango). Both primary and secondary fruits are selected using different Property controls. The result of user selection is displayed on a cross Table. (With the vendors on Vertical axis).

What I want to do is, select an row, that row will have sales of both primary and secondary fruit, I wish to display that how much percentage sales of secondary fruit is more than of primary.

So, If Primary fruit have sales of $ 100 and secondary fruit have sales of $ 120, the bar chart should show Primary fruit bar as 0 % and secondary fruit as 20 %.

Primary fruit will always have a bar of 0 %.

Hope I am clear now.

Is this possible is Spotfire?

TIA.

Comment: Definitely possible. Can you provide a small data set for us to work with

Comment: So how about that dataset? Or have you found a solution and thus should delete the question?